# CSS Custom Shape Arrow

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Although a good tutorial for custom CSS shapes is on `http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/` but I want a shape something like this `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Red_Arrow_Up.svg`. Thx beforehand for this newbie's help.

Zia

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get your question.
Although I have tried "Triangle Up" but I want a bit different shape than that. I don't know where to twist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your exact requirement.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <head>
         <style>
         #star-five {
               margin: 100px 0;
              position: relative;
          display: block;
           color: red;
             width: 0px;
          height: 0px;

         border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
        border-left:   100px solid transparent;
         -moz-transform:    rotate(-38deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg);
         -ms-transform:     rotate(-38deg);
          -o-transform:      rotate(-38deg);
          }
         #star-five:before {

          border-left: 30px solid transparent;
          border-right: 30px solid transparent;
          position: absolute;
          height: 0;
         width: 0;
         top: -45px;
          left: -65px;
        display: block;
        content: '';
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
      -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
       -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
      -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

       }
      #star-five:after {
         position: absolute;
       display: block;
      color: red;
     top: 3px;
     left: -105px;
      width: 0px;
         height: 0px;
       border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 70px solid red;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';
      }


       </style>
      </head>
     <body>
         <div id="star-five">
      </div>
       </body>
```

Comment: Thx a lot Guys!

Praveen's answer was what I was expecting :)

[JS Fiddle]


  http://jsfiddle.net/yuGxT/3/

Zia

Comment: u welcome zia...ask anytime any help. and if u like my answer then vote up my answer also.

Comment: I appreciate :-)
But since I am quite new to the Stackoverflow, I can't vote for your answer, I need 15 reputations for this. Otherwise I have already tried to vote.
I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work by overlaying two separate triangles on top of each other - one red, then a smaller height white triangle above it.

HTML:

```
<div id="triangleContainer">
    <div id="triangleRed"></div>
    <div id="triangleWhite"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#triangleContainer{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
}

#triangleRed {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;left:0;
}

#triangleWhite {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:30px solid white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;left:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuGxT/)

Comment: you could use pseudo-elements instead of those 2 extra `div`s